# PageSpeed Insight - Exploit browser caching for external ressources

Tags: wordpress, performance, pagespeed

I'm trying to improve page speed note for our website. There is no more red flags, but I have some yellow ones. I'm not sure how to deal with those for the browser caching.

Gzip compression is enabled.
But there is still a list of external files who are flagged.

[image]
I am not sure how to deal with those ?

Answer (score 1):

You can deal with them in two ways: a) cache them locally with a higher TTL (some are easier to handle then others, some won't allow it in their terms & conditions) or b) remove them.

Since they are external, you have no power over them, so you can't fix any issues that google's tool suggests.

Comment: Thanks for your time. This is what i found on the other posts too.